# Visual Composer like plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm looking for Visual Composer (of Wordpress) like plugin for TinyMCE. Support for rows and columns would be fine. Does anybody know such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find on codecanyon a plugin which adds a Bootstrap toolbar to tinymce. Not as complete as Visual Composer, but you can make templates with rows and columns, add images, buttons, ... nearly all Bootstrap Elements :

[tinyMce Bootstrap Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/tinymce-bootstrap-plugin/10086522)

This plugin also exists for wordpress :

[Tiny Bootstrap Elements - Wordpress Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/tiny-bootstrap-elements-wordpress-plugin/10293837)

Hope it helps

Comment: Is it possible to use visual composer in php without wordpress, just tinymce editor in normal php project ?